# Set content of textblock

Tags: wpf, textblock

I'm making WPF project. I don't have idea how I can resolve my problem so I post it here.

I made my window, put some buttons, put some checkboxes, and few things more. One of this is `TextBlock` which is empty - I want fill it in future. My `TextBlock` looks like:

```
<TextBlock Name="TxtBlock_sciezkaWejscia" IsEnabled="False" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0"  />
```

In var I have path. I want put this path to my `TextBlock` but I don't have idea how I can do it. I tried some things but it doesn't work, can you solve my problem? Should I use something another than `TextBlock`? `TextBox`?

I tried:

```
TxtBlock_sciezkaWejscia.DataContext = sciezkaPliku;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TextBlock` has a `Text` property that you can set to any `string`:

```
TxtBlock_sciezkaWejscia.Text = "some text...";
```